# How to save modifiable and readonly states in session file?

Tags: sessions

I can’t find how to save `modifiable` and `readonly` states with `:mksession`.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the help for `:mksession`? There it mentions an option [`'sessionoptions`'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'sessionoptions') and if you read that help section you'll see there are various values that dictate what kind of information `:mksession` saves. In your case you need the *options* value:

> *options*  : all options and mappings (also global values for local options)

(I tested it with your two examples, `'modifiable'` and `'readonly'`, fyi.)

So you can do

```
:set sessionoptions+=options
```

What's odd, though, is that *options* is one of the defaults (along with *blank, buffers, curdir, folds, help, tabpages* and *winsize*). Is `'sessionsoptions'` (or `'ssop'`) getting modified in your vimrc or something?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I’ve read the help but probably I didn’t understand that part about `options` and I looked specifically for those that I needed.

I checked my vimrc and found out that I messed with `ssop`. It was from the first time I tried to use sessions.

Comment: And still it does not save file encoding…

Comment: Are you talking about `'fileencoding'`? There's no reason for it to save that in session data. File encoding is directly associated with the buffer file. Save the buffer and the file will be written to disk _with_ that encoding.

Comment: Yes, it’s about `fenc`. The problem is when I start the session Vim opens the file with incorrect encoding and I have to manually `:view ++enc=…`.

Comment: Try opening the file normally (e.g. `:e file`), do `:set fileencoding=XXX` where XXX is whatever it's supposed to be, and save it. Next time you open it it _should_ have encoding XXX. If that doesn't work I suggest you submit a new question with all the details.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work this way. I has been trying to solve this problem since I started learning Vim. Now it's not that necessary since UTF-8 is almost everywhere. However, it's needed from time to time.

Comment: Which encodings are we talking about anyways? That is, when you load without overrides what is value of `'fenc'` and what are you trying to set it to? And while we're at it what values do you have for `'fencs'` and `'encoding'`? (Or is this a general problem and the specific encodings don't matter?)

Comment: I guess the problem is with the algorithm which detects the encoding. My encodings are: `enc=utf-8`, `fenc=cp866`, `fencs=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,cp866,latin1`, while the file in question is opened with `fenc=cp1251` which is my ANSI encoding and `default` (I am on Windows). The algorithm cannot distinguish between cp866 and cp1251 — if I save the file in cp1251 and change the `fencs=...,cp866,default,...` it will be opened in cp866.